# Can someone help to find the reason for s runtime error in this code?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

The code runs fine in my compiler but shows runtime error on codeforces. I found out that I should avoid unitialized variables but I think I've already covered that.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, n, flag = 1, k = 1;
    int hours[n];
    int minutes[n];

    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> hours[i];
        cin >> minutes[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (hours[i] == hours[i + 1] && minutes[i] == minutes[i + 1])
        {
            flag++;
            if (flag > k)
                k = flag;
        }
        else
            flag = 1;

    }
    cout << k;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the `n` value here `int hours[n];` ? You need to initialize `n` before this statement. Move this `cin >> n;` before `int hours[n];`.

Comment: `hours[i]==hours[i+1]&&minutes[i]==minutes[i+1]`  --- `i+1` out of range

Comment: `int hours[n]` and `int minutes[n]` are a big red flag. You are trying to use the feature variable length arrays which are not part of strict C++ standard(it is a compiler feature and not all compiler support them), either have a constant size or use `std::vector<int>` from C++ STL.

Comment: Achtually, just dont ue VLAs like `int hours[n]` at all, they are not part of the language standard! use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The only variables you initialise are `k` and `flag`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies here

```cpp
int i, n, flag = 1, k = 1;
int hours[n];
int minutes[n];
```

You declare variables `n`, but you don't initialize it, and then you use it to specify an array size. Uninitialized variables of type `int` contain garbage data, and using it is undefined behavior, whatever happens is unspecified, and you can not rely on it.

If you must create an array of size specified by a user input, you need to allocate at runtime.

```cpp
int *hours;
int *minutes;

cin >> n;

hours = new int[n];
minutes = new int[n];

// Rest of the code

// Remember to delete them
delete[] minutes;
delete[] hours;
```

Better yet, use a container provided by the standard library, a `std::vector` would be a perfect container to use here

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> hours;
std::vector<int> minutes;

cin >> n

hours.resize(n);
minutes.resize(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

VLAs are not standard C++ but are allowed as an extension. The first problem in your code is that you use the variable `n` without initialization. This causes undefined behavior according to the standard.

You need to move the call to `cin()` to above the arrays that use `n` at declaration. The second problem in your code is that the expression inside the `if` statement attempts to access an element outside the bounds of your array. This also causes undefined behavior.

Here is a refined version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int k = 1;
    int flag = 1;

    cout << "Enter a value for n:" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    int *hours = new int[n];
    int *minutes = new int[n];

    cout << "Enter values for hours:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ":";
        cin >> hours[i];
    }

    cout << "Enter values for minutes:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ":";
        cin >> minutes[i];
    }

    // note here: 'i' goes to (n - 1) instead of (n) so as not to be out of range
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if ((hours[i] == hours[i + 1]) && (minutes[i] == minutes[i + 1]))
        {
            flag++;
            if (flag > k)
            {
                k = flag;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 1;
        }

    }
    cout << "The value of k is: " << k << endl;
    delete hours;
    delete minutes;
    return 0;
}
```